# Creating a dynamic crystal report

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a word document template for a report which consists of 3-4 paragraphs. The contents of this report can change. Hence I am thinking of an option to upload this word document template by the user or can be typed by the user through a text box, whenever he needs to print the report.
I need to populate this report with data from the data base also.

Is it possible to populate a template word document with data from database through crystal report
or is it possible to type the report contents through a text box and populate report with data from database(sql server 2008) using a crystal report(in web application).

I am using visual studion 2010 and SAP crystal report VS 13.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be possible. For taking data from database you can create dataset and tables. its easy for implement. [Click here to create crystal report](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rsubhajit/CrystalReportwithDataSet03012006060655AM/CrystalReportwithDataSet.aspx)